# New method, <identifier> expected error

Tags: java, methods, identifier

I'm trying to write a program (for an assignment) that will – based on two absolute parameters – determine wether or not someone will be eligible for financial support. To accomplish this I have created three new methods, and currently I'm down to 1 error that I simply cannot comprehend. The error says "identifier expected" on this part of the code (in the bottom:

static void metodeTekst(tekst)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinOppgave2a
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String tastatur;

      System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\r\n" + "For aa kunne beregne ditt stoettegrunnlag, må du oppgi alderen din: ");
    tastatur = in.nextLine();
    int alder = Integer.parseInt(tastatur);
      System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\r\n" + "Bor du hjemme? Skriv 1 for «Ja», eller 2 for «Nei»: ");
    tastatur = in.nextLine();
    int hjemme = Integer.parseInt(tastatur);
      System.out.println();


    int i = 0;

    while (i < 2)
    {
        i = i + 0;
    }

    metodeAlder(alder);
    metodeHjemme(hjemme);

    System.out.println("Du vil faa full studiestoette!");

  }
  static void metodeAlder(int alder)
  {
    if (alder <= 18 || alder >= 45)
      i++;

    else
      metodeTekst(tekst);
  }
  static void metodeHjemme(int hjemme)
  {
    if (hjemme == 2)
      i++;

    else
      metodeTekst(tekst);

  }
  static void metodeTekst(tekst)
  {
    String tekst = ("Du vil faa redusert eller ingen studiestoette.");
    System.out.println(tekst);
  }
}
```

I've tried for a good while to find an answer online, but in most cases where people have gotten this error they have forgotten to write a main method. I have not, as you see. Thanks in advance – I'm really new to Java, and appreciate all help!

Comment: `tekst` should have a type, e.g. `String tekst`. (Or be removed altogether since it's not used.)

Answer (score 1):

Your method `metodeTekst` is wrong. It should either be

```
static void metodeTekst()
{
    String tekst = "Du vil faa redusert eller ingen studiestoette.";
    System.out.println(tekst);
}
```

or

```
static void metodeTekst(String tekst)
{
    System.out.println(tekst);
}
```

but then you have to call it like this:

```
metodeTekst("Du vil faa redusert eller ingen studiestoette.");
```

**Edit for OP's comment:**

There are many additional problems with your code. The variable `i` in `metodeAlder` and `metodeHjemme` is outside if the scope of where `i` is initially defined (in `main`). If you really need to alter this variable inside your methods you have to declare it as a `static` field outside of your main.

Besides after everything compiles fine, this part

```
 while (i < 2)
 {
     i = i + 0;
 }
```

is pointless. You'll end up in an endless loop since you never change `i` so it will always be `< 2`. I would remove all occurrences of `i` since it doesn't do any meaningful and is not at all needed in your program.

**Edit 2:**

For your question as to why the compiler only now complains about `i`: It first checked, if all your method signatures were correct. Since it ran into previous error (with the wrong signature), it didn't need to check further. Now that you've fixed it, the compiler could continue to check the syntax "inside" the methods. And since `i` is only defined outisde of the method's scopes, it didn't know what `i` is supposed to be, hence the next compiler error.

**Edit 3:**

To make my explanation clearer look at the following example:

```
{
    // Outer Scope
    {
        // Inner Scope A
    }
    {
        // Inner Scope B
    }
    {
        // Inner Scope C
    }
}
```

Here, the three inner scopes `A, B, C` are isolated from each other. So variables defined in inner scope `A` are not visible to the other inner scopes `B` and `C`. In contrast, variables defined in the outer scope are visible to all inner scopes, since they are part of the outer scope as well.

Comment: Thanks! Tried the latter method now, solved the initial problem. However, now the compiler complains that it cannot find symbol i++; in either of its places. Is there any good reason why I did not get this earlier, and as to why I'm getting it now? As far as I understand, I've declared i in the main method – shouldn't the program be able to access it in the other methods then?

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. But I will need some form of counter to ensure that the program only does print the last line in main once certain requirements are fulfilled. Isn't an i++-counter the best way to do this, in combination with a while loop?

Comment: A `while`-loop is certainly the way to go here, but right now, your loop does absolutely nothing and will continue forever. Your two methods won't ever be called since they come after the while loop. You have to put your **whole** logic (i.e. asking for user input and checking for validity) into your `while`-loop. Then, if both of your conditions you want to check are met, you can `break` out of your loop.